# Setting process.env var in package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

I am trying to set and retrieve node app process.env vars using package.json, so by researching the issue, I've found an example to set / retrieve process.env through the 'config' section, so I added a new config section as shown below :

```
"config" : { "var1" : "test", "var2" : "test2", "var3" : "test3" },
```

But I couldn't access any of the above vars from server.js using for example:

```
console.log(process.env.npm_package_config_var1);
```

So I was wondering how I can set / retrieve process.env var using package.json? Thanks

*I am using npm 4.4.1, node 7.4.0 and I run the app using (npm run dev)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot just set environment variables in package.json.

You can set them in your script sections using:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "ENV_VAR=abc node app.js",
},
```

or:

```
 "scripts": {
  "start": "cross-env ENV_VAR=abc node app.js",
},
```

using the cross-env module. See:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env

Environment variables are something that your programs get at runtime, not something stored in a config - unless you use something like dotenv, see:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

but this is using the `.env` file, not package.json.

Comment: vote for `Environment variables are something that your programs get at runtime, not something stored in a config `

Answer (score 7):

> You cannot just set environment variables in package.json.

[Yes you can.](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#config)

You may try out `node -p process.env` as your npm script to inspect your env variable. And ensure that nothing else overwrites your values. Here is another [example](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#special-packagejson-config-object) which works for me.

Comment: should add the prefix `npm_package_config_`, it's of importance

Answer (score 3):

I don't really understand, what are you trying to do.

But if you want to retrieve env variables you have to do define your dev script in your `package.json` like this : `NODE_ENV=dev node index.js`

Then fetch your env with : `process.env.NODE_ENV`

Comment: he means he wants to set lots of k-v pairs like `a=xxx b=xxx c=xxx node index.js`，and wonder if there's a config file can do this work

Answer (score 1):

This will only work if you start your application using npm:

so have:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
},
"config" : { "var1" : "test", "var2" : "test2", "var3" : "test3" }
```

then:

```
npm run start
```

and within server.js this will display the variable correctly:

```
console.log(process.env.npm_package_config_var1);
```